# A good image upload class using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, image, file-upload, image-uploading

I have written a class to handle image uploads in PHP. Is this is good image upload class? If you see the code given below, the insert mysql query happens only when move_uploaded_file() function uploads the file successfully to the server. Otherwise it exits with an error. Is there any better practise other than this.? Do I need to look for any other situations or exceptions or methods.?

```
<?php
    /**
    * This is a image upload Calss
    */
    class Images // define the calss
    {
        public $_remane = false;  //remane false
        public $_savetodb;
        public $_target_dir = "uploads";

        function __construct()//Constructor
        {
            # code...
        }

        public function displayImages($userids){
            $qr = mysql_query("SELECT id,img_name, img_order FROM images
                               WHERE usersid =".$userids."
                               ORDER BY img_order"); 

            $resp = array();
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qr))
            {
                $resp[] = array("img_id" => $row['id'],"img_name" => $row['img_name'],"img_order" => $row['img_order']);  
            }
            return $resp;
        }// End of displayImages

        public function displayAllImages($userids = null){
            if($userids == null){
                $usersData = mysql_query("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS uid
                               FROM users WHERE role_id =2");
                $allids=mysql_fetch_object($usersData);    

                $userids = $allids->uid;           
            }

            $qr = mysql_query("SELECT img_name, usersid, users.email_id 
                               FROM images
                               LEFT JOIN users on images.usersid = users.id 
                               WHERE usersid in (".$userids.")");

            $resp = array();
            if($qr){
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qr))
                {
                    $resp[] = array("email_id" => $row['email_id'],"img_name" => $row['img_name'],"usersid" => $row['usersid']);  
                }
                return $resp;           
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }

        }

        public function validateImages(){
            foreach ($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'] as $f => $name) {
                //Check Each Image Type.
                $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"][$f]);
                if($check == false) {
                    $uploadOk = 0;
                    return false;
                } 
            }
            return true;
        }//End of validateImages


        public function handelUpload(){
            //Check if the folder is exixts
            if (!file_exists($this->_target_dir)) {
                        mkdir($this->_target_dir, 0777, true);
            }
            $uploadOk = 1;  
            foreach ($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'] as $f => $name) {
                $imageFileType = pathinfo($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"][$f],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                if($this->_remane === true){
                    $imageFileName = substr(md5(rand()), 0, 7)."_".time().'.'.$imageFileType;
                }
                else{
                    $imageFileName = basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"][$f]);
                }
                $target_file = $this->_target_dir.'/'.$imageFileName;


                $count=0;

                // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
                if ($uploadOk == 0) {
                // if everything is ok, try to upload file
                } else {
                    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"][$f], $target_file)) {
                        try {
                            $qr = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM images WHERE usersid = '".$_SESSION['userid']."'");  
                            $order = mysql_num_rows($qr); 
                            $qr = mysql_query("INSERT INTO images(usersid, img_name, img_order) values('".$_SESSION['userid']."','".$imageFileName."','".$order."')") or die(mysql_error());  
                            continue;
                        }catch (Exception $e) {
                            echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
                        }// End of Catch
                    } //End of If upload
                }//End of Else
            }//End foreach

            if($uploadOk == 1){ //Image upload Successful
                return true;
            }else{ //Image upload fails
                return false;
            }
        }//End of handelUpload


    }// End of calss
    ?>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                           <fieldset>
                                Select image to upload:
                                <input type="file" name="fileToUpload[]" id="fileToUpload" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*">   
                           </fieldset>

                            <fieldset>
                               <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">    
                            </fieldset>
                         </form>
```

Comment: Never insert raw values directly into a database without checking their validity. Always use placeholders. The code above is susceptible to a SQL injection.
Examples can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: I guess you should post this to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/